# iOS: Duplicated view positioning

Tags: ios, view, positioning

My purpose is to duplicate a view and position it correctly.
So I'm cloning a view with

```
- (UIView *)cloneView:(UIView *)view {
    NSData *viewArchive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:view];
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:viewArchive];
}
```

Then I'm trying to position cloned view by changing it's `frame` property.
Sometimes I need to make `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` **before**.

The problem occures when I try to reposition subviews of cloned view.
I've noticed that if that subview is UIView instance, then everything is OK.
But when I try to reposition UILabel, it just ignore all changes to `frame`.

So, the question is:
How should I make it right?
What is the best practice to duplicate a view and change it's frame and frames of it's children?

PS:
Also, I've asked somewhat [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29493830/858602).

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just subclass UIView, lay it out in your subclass, and instantiate it twice? I think this is a pretty convoluted way to do this. It sounds like there might be some magic happening when your views layout that wasn't provided here for us to see. On a hunch I might hold on to your views as instance variables and try to set their frames on  -(void)layoutSubviews. Provide your layout code if you can.

Comment: @Dare, actually I'm a big noob in iOS development. And this is the solution I've found to create a clone of my view. Can you please point, how can I create a subclass of UIView to fill it with other subviews.